# Had had (Is it a past perfect or past simple)

Tags: grammaticality

Look at the sentence that is in Italic. I wonder if had had there is the past-perfect or is it the Past Simple followed by 'had to'? I'm confused.

> Helen stepped outside her front door to see what the weather was like.
>   It was sunny and warm. That was nice, because for the past two weeks
>   it had been cold and rainy. *It had been so cold that she **had had** to
>   turn her heater on.* She was lucky, because her heater worked and she
>   could pay her heating bills.

Comment: Assuming it is the Past-Perfect, I also wonder why this tense appears twice in the sentence, instead of the ordinary formula of past-pefect+past simple.  **(It had been so cold that she had had to turn her heater on)**. Perhaps because we have 3 past times, rather than 2? First one: cold in. Second: turning the heather, third: stepping outside (two weeks later). Or perhaps it is just interchangeable like suggested [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/114240/it-had-been-a-long-time-since-past-perfect-or-past-simple)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The past perfect is used to talk about actions that happened before something else. The story is told in the past simple. To refer to *the past two weeks*, we need to change the tense to the past perfect.

*She had had to turn* is the past perfect form of *she has to turn*.

> It had been so cold that she **had needed to turn** her heater on.
>
> The cold **had forced her to turn** her heater on.

Comment: I see. Just to say that I don't understand what in the passage indicates that the story is told in the present simple as you mentioned. To me, it seems like the past-simple. _"Helen stepped outside..."_

Comment: @SunnySideDown it was a typo, corrected